# React proptypes when using shape cannot validate

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I got a react component that doesn't want to validate props, I can't understand why.

This is the component :

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useGridApiContext } from "@mui/x-data-grid-premium";
import Utils from "utils/utils";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export function TimeEditInputCell({ props }) {
  const { id, value, field } = props;

  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({
      id,
      field,
      value: newValue,
      debounceMs: 1000,
    });
  };

  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key.toLowerCase() === "enter") {
      const ignoreCellModeRow = {
        id: id,
        ignoreModifications: false,
      };
      apiRef.current.stopRowEditMode(ignoreCellModeRow);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      onKeyDown={(e) => onKeyDown(e)}
      defaultValue={Utils.minutesToString(value)}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}

TimeEditInputCell.propTypes = {
  props: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    field: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
};
```

I've got no error in console, however when I run linter I got these errors :

```
  7:11  warning  'id' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  7:15  warning  'value' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  7:22  warning  'field' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

I tried to define these variables outside from shape, which make pass the linter but then it throws error in console in browser because it's undefined (obviously since it's not defined)

**EDIT** :

I could make it work but I lose verifications by doing it this way :

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useGridApiContext } from "@mui/x-data-grid-premium";
import Utils from "utils/utils";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export function TimeEditInputCell({ rowInformations }) {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({
      id: rowInformations.id,
      field: rowInformations.field,
      value: newValue,
      debounceMs: 1000,
    });
  };

  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key.toLowerCase() === "enter") {
      const ignoreCellModeRow = {
        id: rowInformations.id,
        ignoreModifications: false,
      };
      apiRef.current.stopRowEditMode(ignoreCellModeRow);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      onKeyDown={(e) => onKeyDown(e)}
      defaultValue={Utils.minutesToString(rowInformations.value)}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}

TimeEditInputCell.propTypes = {
  rowInformations: PropTypes.object,
};
```

But I'm still not fine with that solution since it makes verifications less precise